# My score refuses to change

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Look into my [profile](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/users/967/bleh), and you will see my score for Greek hasn't changed.

How? Can anyone fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag scores do not update instantly. I think it updates once a day.

I'm not sure what you think it hasn't changed *from*, but your [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) score is currently 13. I counted your answers and it adds up correctly.

Note that only **answers** are counted for scores.

Comment: On my activity thingie that checks my score. What about that?

Comment: @bleh You mean reputation? Those update faster.

Comment: Like the thing under it- the tag badge

Comment: That is what I originally refer to. Thy update slowly. If you think something is wrong still, take a screenshot and show us.